# How to return multiple DNS A records in a specific order using bind9?

Tags: debian, bind, bind9

I have a bind9 testing environment in Debian wheezy that I am trying to set up two A records that are returned in a fixed order.  In my `named.conf.options` file I have the following configuration:

```
options {
    ...
    rrset-order { order fixed; };
};
```

This is functional to the point that my records are always returned in the same order, but the problem is that bind is choosing to sort them numerically (smallest numbers first) and I am trying to sort them the other direction.

Based on [this link](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/queries.html#rrset-order) I understand that the `fixed` keyword should set the response to whatever order I've got in my configuration file.  However, I cannot alter the order of the returned results by changing the order of the records in the zone file.

Does anyone know how to return multiple A records for a DNS address in a specific order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind9 on Wheezy doesn't allow for that option. Also one must ask himself why one wants/needs this as it breaks when it hits the cache of some recursor. Also for failover purposes it is not really suited as most clients don't have the code to make that happen.

If you maintain the client code, then having a look into SRV resource records that allow you to set priority and load settings for every record. But this depends on the rest of your problem that you try to solve.

Answer (score 3):

The next paragraph in the reference to which [you linked](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/queries.html#rrset-order) explains why this cannot work with Debian's implementation of `bind9`:

> Note: For reasons best known to the ISC (BIND's author) the fixed
>   value is now (BIND 9.6+) only available if the configure option
>   --with-fixed-rrset is used in the build. Neither BSD nor Debian standard packages use this option. This is likely to be true for
>   Fedora and other RPMs but has not been verified (use named -V to
>   check). For practical purposes only cyclic and random are the
>   available choices.